# Vlookup by match cases

Tags: excel, database, join, match, vlookup

I have two different datasets with different data structure.

[image]

categories are similar.So i want to vlook the datasets based on the word match. Is it possible in excel workbook?

I tried Vlookuping the data, but they are adding based on exact match.

Comment: So use wildcards. If you want either entry that contains “restaurant” then use “*restaurant*” etc

Comment: Or you could do a substitute() and replace any entry that contains “*beauty*” with “beauty” etc

Comment: @ Solar Mike can you please elaborate

Comment: use * as the wildcard, so Xbeauty allows any text before beauty... beautyX allows any text after... F*cking editor on here takes the * to indicate italic... so I used X...

Answer (score 0):

A simple exposition of the use of wildcards:

[image]

So no wildcard, before, after, both before & after and just finding the first 3 characters...

So, just using your example with additions:

[image]